# Display entire json object on page

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know there's a way to do this, but I can't remember, and I think it involves `$index`. I'd like to display all the data within an ng-repeat. When I've done this in the past, it displays everything within the page's HTML so it's like:

array: [ { animal: "dog", color: "brown" }, {animal: "cat", color: "orange"} ]

Rather than the formatted version you see in your console.

```
array: [ 
    { 
      animal: "dog",
      color: "brown"
    },
    {
      animal: "cat",
      color: "orange"
    } 
]
```

I am doing this because I need to access a hidden array that is generated in the scope. I cannot add anything to or edit the `$scope`, and didn't do so in the past when I was able to remember how to do such a thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if I've misunderstood, but if you're just trying to render an object in json format for debugging purposes you can use the [json filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json).

Example from docs:

```
<pre id="default-spacing">{{ {'name':'value'} | json }}</pre>
<pre id="custom-spacing">{{ {'name':'value'} | json:4 }}</pre>
```

Result:

```
{
  "name": "value"
}

{
    "name": "value"
}
```